# HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@3e5a91e1 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, hikaricp

i just update the jhipster project from 4.14.3 to 4.14.4,i remained mostly code that generated on 4.14.3 the code is [here](https://gitee.com/jnuc093/pmt-m),before updated it run successfully,but after updated when i use ./mvnw to start the background it return:

```
    2018-06-04 22:07:11.189  WARN 71364 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: All Hibernate caches should be created upfront. Please update CacheConfiguration.java to add com.sgcc.syn.domain.Authority
2018-06-04 22:07:11.209  WARN 71364 --- [ pmt-Executor-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@3e5a91e1 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1184)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1179)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4523)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:377)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:337)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1166)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:205)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:170)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:77)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2018-06-04 22:07:11.210  WARN 71364 --- [ pmt-Executor-1] liquibase                                : Failed to restore the auto commit to true
2018-06-04 22:07:11.210 ERROR 71364 --- [ pmt-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:363)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.close(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1202)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:397)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:77)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:490)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:395)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:361)
    ... 8 common frames omitted

2018-06-04 22:07:11.218 ERROR 71364 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: All Hibernate caches should be created upfront. Please update CacheConfiguration.java to add com.sgcc.syn.domain.Authority
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
```

how can i resolve it.

Comment: sorry,i resoled it.i forget CacheManager construct in DatabaseConfiguration.the resolved code is here.
https://gitee.com/jnuc093/pmt-m/commit/e28f5024680c9bcf3b52ed0b4efd60812da39a8e

Comment: Since is invalidated now, could you please suggest the solution?